# Batch - Natives, Jars, and loose class files

Tags: java, windows, eclipse, batch-file

I am running Windows 7 64-bit.

I would like to make a .bat file that will run my eclipse project's main.class using (preferably) only that .bat file. The project is still undergoing construction so exporting a runnable jar every few minutes isn't an acceptable solution (nor is installing eclipse on all machines). Furthermore I don't really want to install any more plug-ins, I know there is a way to do this with a .bat but haven't been able to figure it out. Here is what the project root folder looks like:

C:/.../ShootEmUp <-inside there we have:

```
bin/
lib/
    natives/
    lots of .jar files
res/
src/
    ShootEm/
        OtherPackages/
        ShootEmMain.java
.classpath
.project
RunMe.bat
```

I have tried more combinations inside the .bat file than I care to admit. Right now RunMe.bat looks like:

```
@ECHO OFF

javac src.ShootEm.ShootEmMain.java
java -cp lib/*.jar;. src/ShootEm/ShootEmMain;

PAUSE
```

This currently produces a javac: file not found: src.ShootEm.ShootEmMain.java error

I have also tried putting the .bat inside the folder ShootEmUp/src/ShootEm/ (next to the class with public static void main [ShootEmMain.java]) and editing the RunMe.bat code to:

```
@ECHO OFF

javac ShootEmMain.java
java -cp ../../lib/*.jar;. ShootEmMain;

PAUSE
```

This seemed to work a little better as the error I would get then was:

ShootEmMain.java:5: error: package ... does not exist. (the a whole bunch more for all the other jars in the lib folder)

It's useful to note I've already added C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin; to the front of the value of the Path environment variable.

I have also tried classpath instead of cp and a whole crazy list of syntax combinations for each (once I was well past frustrated) to no avail.

Also I realize my .bat example doesn't set the natives as I'm not really sure where that fits into this mess. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at using a tool like [ant](http://ant.apache.org/) or [maven](http://maven.apache.org/) to build your application. This will streamline producing your artifact.

If it's unreasonable to export a working jar across your environment, I boggle at how you could imagine it's more manageable to export your source code around your environment.

Comment: Ant may work. I am confused as to what you meant by exporting source around the environment. I didn't want to move anything out of the folder eclipse is using. Just create a batch file inside it that would allow for double click execution of the project. If I get ant to work as anticipated I'll choose this as my accepted answer and forget the batch file, assuming it isn't possible.

Comment: It's possible to compile your code using a batch file, but it's unnecessarily complex.

Comment: RE exporting code: "so exporting a runnable jar every few minutes isn't an acceptable solution (nor is installing eclipse on all machines). " My only guess as to why you're writing this batch file is to get your changes to your other machines, or as an attempt to make your project not rely on Eclipse (Which is a great goal).

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry I completely misread that! Yeah I'd rather our artist and tester not need to install eclipse (there's just too much they could mess up).

Comment: If you want to ensure your testers have the most up-to-date artifacts, you should look at using maven over ant, as maven also provides a better mechanism for archiving your artifacts, and has a built in mechanism for versioning.